# NTLM/ Kerberos Authorisation for Django on Ubuntu with Nginx

Tags: django, apache, ubuntu, nginx, ntlm

I have a Django website as an on-going development which I have running on Ubuntu 16.04.1. It is an intranet and so sits within a corporate network.

It currently works nicely with Nginx, Gunicorn and Supervisor.

However, I would now like to implement single sign on so that users who have already authenticated into their workstations don’t have to sign into the application. As I understand from, the Django documentation, setting the REMOTE_USER environment variable is key and, during my efforts, I have been able to set this variable in my current Nginx config and it authenticates to the Django site.

However, the network environment means that I am looking for a solution that uses with NTLM or Kerberos (rather than Based Auth, which I believe would make this much easier for me although I’m currently unfamiliar with all of them.)

In trying to find internet posts that would help be do this (including on here), [I’m not 100% sure that it would actually be possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21284935/nginx-reverse-proxy-with-windows-authentication-that-uses-ntlm/33096713#).

Does anyone know if it is using recent versions of nginx (1.10) ? If not, am I likely to have more success with some sort of Apache set up ( using mod_wsgi instead of Gunicorn as this post [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3787379/8037244) would insinuate.