# Nginx proxy_pass ntlm authorization

Tags: nginx

```
proxy_pass   http://myserver;
proxy_redirect off;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forward-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

Above is my nginx configuration, and *myserver* requires **NTLM** authentication.
I access *myserver* through nginx proxy and provide correct auth info,but the browser prompt auth again.

Any wrong with my configuration?

**EIDT:**
Referred to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/754351/what-is-a-correct-ways-to-allow-login-to-an-iis-site-through-a-reverse-proxy) ,I use stream proxy and problem solved!

Thanks to @Tarun Lalwani

Comment: Your question says basic auth, your title says ntlm auth?

Comment: It's NTLM. I have updated the question.

Comment: See if this https://serverfault.com/questions/754351/what-is-a-correct-ways-to-allow-login-to-an-iis-site-through-a-reverse-proxy or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21284935/nginx-reverse-proxy-with-windows-authentication-that-uses-ntlm helps?

Comment: @Tarun Lalwani Great! I solved my problem using stream proxy. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

According to nginx documentation:

> Allows proxying requests with NTLM Authentication. The upstream connection is bound to the client connection once the client sends a request with the “Authorization” header field value starting with “Negotiate” or “NTLM”. Further client requests will be proxied through the same upstream connection, keeping the authentication context.

```
upstream http_backend {
    server 127.0.0.1:8080;

    ntlm;
}
```

The "ntlm" option is available only for Nginx Plus.
I created a custom module that is able to provide a similar functionality

[gabihodoroaga/nginx-ntlm-module](https://github.com/gabihodoroaga/nginx-ntlm-module)

There is also a blog post about this at [hodo.dev](https://hodo.dev/posts/post-18-nginx-ntlm-module/)